# CSS :not and :first-child for same class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list with html/css with same class names and the first X class have more class. I need to add a red border for the first li item, which not have pluss class names. I can't use nth element because numbers of the "product-cat" class named li sometimes changes. I tried a lot of combinations but I can't do that. Any idea?

```
<ul>
<li class="product product-cat"></li>
<li class="product product-cat"></li>
<li class="product product-cat"></li>
<li class="product"></li> /*I want to add red border for this li item*/
<li class="product"></li>
<li class="product"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following:

```css
.product {
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.product-cat {
  background: green;
}

/**
 * the above code is only for demonstration purposes.
 * please check the code below
 */

.product:not(.product-cat) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.product:not(.product-cat) + .product {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product product-cat"></li>
  <li class="product product-cat"></li>
  <li class="product product-cat"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
</ul>
```

This applies the desired border to all list items that only have the `.product` class and then skips over the first `.product` item and removes the border again.